# 90th percentile latency of memcached

Tags: memcached, libmemcached

I'm running the memaslap client from libmemcached 1.0.16  to benchmark memcached-1.4.15 and I want to get the 90th percentile latency.

Is there a good way to get it from memaslap?

Or are there other benchmark tools that make it easier to extract the 90th percentile latency?

Answer (score 0):

If you run run memaslap from the command line with the -q9 flag it should return the number you need.

Comment: That doesn't work, but -S outputs dynamic statistics, including the min, max and avg latency but not the percentiles. Ultimately I gave up using memaslap and switched to **mutilate** (https://github.com/leverich/mutilate) which gives the 5th, 10th, 90th, 95th and 99th percentiles